# Taking mean of same values in a data frame

Tags: r, aggregate

In the following data frame, I need to take the mean of all values in `a, b , c`

```
values <- data.frame(value = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                           "b", "b", "b", 
                           "c", "c", "c", "c"), i = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

To achieve this, I tried using `aggregate` function as follows:

```
agg <- aggregate(values, by = list(values$value), FUN = mean)
```

The output does result in the mean values of `i` but I do not think this is the correct way. The output also throws a couple of warnings.

```
Warning messages:
    1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
  2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
  3: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
  > agg
  Group.1 value    i
  1       a    NA  3.0
  2       b    NA  7.0
  3       c    NA 10.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the warning message with:

```
aggregate(values, by = list(values$value), FUN = function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
```

Which returns:

> ```
>   Group.1 value    i
> 1       a     1  3.0
> 2       b     2  7.0
> 3       c     3 10.5
> ```

Alternatively, we could use dot notation:

```
aggregate(. ~ value, values, mean)
```

Or use formulas:

```
aggregate(i ~ value, values, mean)
```

Both return:

> ```
>   value    i
> 1     a  3.0
> 2     b  7.0
> 3     c 10.5
> ```

Comment: What if `value` is associated with a third variable that also repeats itself? For example in `aggregate(AverageTemperature ~ Year, americanCities, mean)`, _Year_ will be associated with multiple cities` . The above formula will give an average of all years (associated with multiple cities). How can I segregate based on cities? _Note: Here year also repeats itself 12 times in one year_

Comment: You could use `+`. Something like `aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, warpbreaks, mean)`

Comment: Also, is it possible to aggregate based on a condition? For example, I want to aggregate where `year >= 1800 and year < 1900` and second where `year >= 1900`?

Comment: You could subset the data like so, `aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, warpbreaks[warpbreaks$wool == "A", ], mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another easy solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

values %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  summarise(i = mean(i))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   value     i
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      a   3.0
2      b   7.0
3      c  10.5
```